# Symfony - Sending POST from outside

Tags: php, symfony

So I have this controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/submit", name="submit")
 */
public function submitAction(Request $request) {
    var_dump($request->getMethod());
}
```

Now If I create the form in my twig template with

```
<form action="{{ path('submit') }}" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`getMethod` returns POST

But If I do the exact same thing, but using the full url in the action, like this

`<form action="http://domain.my/submit" method="post">`

The the `getMethod` returns GET instead.

How do I fix this?

Comment: So, if I understood well, you are trying to send request from another website ? Do you have any exception ? did you check if CORS are allowed ?

Comment: Correct, and it is intended for this one controller - Is it possible to turn CORS off for this controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well very simple

https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle

```
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/xml/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST']
```